# Function doesn't behave as expected

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

```
f[h_, y_] := y^2 + D[h[y], y]
```

Applying `f` once works fine

```
f[g, y]
```

gives

```
y^2 + Derivative[1][g][y]
```

But applying `f` twice doesn't work.

```
f[f[g, y], y]
```

> `y^2 + Derivative[1][(y^2 + Derivative[1][g][y])][y] + (2 y + (g''[y])[y]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or alternatively:

```
    ff[g_] := D[g, x]

    ff[x^2 + h[x]]
```

Result: 2 x + Derivative[1][h][x]

```
    ff[ff[x^2 + h[x]]]
```

Result: 2 + (h^[Prime][Prime])[x]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this?

```
f[h_, y_] := y^2 + D[h, y]
f[f[g[y], y], y]
```

> 2 y + y^2 + Derivative[2][g][y]

Answer (score 0):

Keep your original definition but add another piece to your definition to handle a second argument pattern:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[h_, y_] := y^2 + D[h[y], y]
f[a : _[__], y_] := y^2 + D[a, y]

f[g, y] // TeXForm
```

> $g'(y)+y^2 $

```
f[g[y], y] // TeXForm
```

> $ g'(y)+y^2$

```
f[f[g, y], y] // TeXForm (* or Nest[f[#, y] &, g, 2] *)
```

> $ g''(y)+y^2+2 y$

```
f[f[g[y], y], y] // TeXForm (* or Nest[f[#, y] &, g[y], 2] *)
```

> $g''(y)+y^2+2 y$

```
f[f[f[g, y], y], y] // TeXForm (* or Nest[f[#, y] &, g, 3] *)
```

> $ g^{(3)}(y)+y^2+2 y+2 $